# Using Regex selecting text match everything after a word or patterns (similar topic but text is not fix patterns except 1 character)

Tags: regex, replace, substring, notepad++, textselection

I am trying to use Regex in notepad++ to select everything after `v+(number|character)*` but in the selection it should excluded the `v+(num|char)*`.

e.g. `master\_\move_consolidate_archives_html_to_move_base_v2kjkj_(2021_01_19_11h43m59s-fi_m_dt xx-) - Copy (2).bat"`

I am expecting

```
_(2021_01_19_11h43m59s-fi_m_dt xx-) - Copy (2).bat"
```

so far I can use this line `(?i)(v\d[0-9a-z]*)`
to select `v2kjkj`

but I can't get this to work with lookbehind `(?<=xxxx)`.
I am also trying to use if-then-else condition but no luck for me. I am still don't understand enough to using it.

issue.
because the "v" have different pattern in it. I can't hard code to certain string

```
v2
v23
v2kjkj
v2343434
```

**Test string:**

```
mmaster\_\move_consolidate_archives_html_to_move_base_v2_16_.bat"
master\_\move_consolidate_archiv es_html_to_move_base_v23_17_.bat"
master\_\move_consolidate_archives_html_to_move_base_v2_17_(2021_01_19_12h37m19s-fi_m_dt xx-).bat"
master\_\move_consolidate_archives_html_to_move_base_v2_(2021_01_19_11h43m59s-fi_m_dt xx-) - CopyCopy.bat"
master\_\move_consolidate_archives_html_to_move_base_v2kjkj_(2021_01_19_11h43m59s-fi_m_dt xx-) - Copy (2).bat"
master\_\move_consolidate_archives_html_to_move_base_v2343434_(2021_01_19_11h43m59s-fi_m_dt xx-) - Copy (3).bat"
```

I have been reading and searching for a day but I can't apply anything I have seen so for.
the closest one I see was

- Regexp match everything after a word
- Getting the text that follows after the regex match

I am welcome any comments.

Comment: _Question 1_: is there a maximum number of `(number|character)`?. _Question 2_: if you are replacing, can't you just wrap the `v+(number|character)*` part in a capturing group and replace it as-is?

Comment: Ans1. maximum (number|char) not encounter so far. what I have seen just v+random char and/or number for certain string as example above

Ans2. I am not sure if I understand your suggestions correctly or not, basically I want to replace/delete text after v+random+ (not the {1} itself)

thank you

Comment: What is the expected result for the test cases?

Comment: I mean you could replace `(?i)(v\d[0-9a-z]*).*` with `\1` (see demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/NwqFp8/1)).

Comment: your demo is amazing, thank you for showing and clarify. I have to put this expression in script eg.filename;s/exp//; from what I understand s/_expr_/_replace_/ it select the string and replace. I don't know if the replace part can put \1 or not. I will try now and let you know.

Comment: reply:toto select everything after not include v+random eg.master\_\move_consolidate_archives_html_to_move_base_v2kjkj_(2021_01_19_11h43m59s-fi_m_dt xx-) - Copy (2).bat. 

I want this part 
**_(2021_01_19_11h43m59s-fi_m_dt xx-) - Copy (2).bat**

Comment: @JamesBell Please notice that your script language may use a more powerful regex engine than Notepad++. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular-expression_engines

Comment: your suggestions work well and thank you for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `v\d[0-9a-z]*\K.*$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
v               # a "v"
\d              # a digit
[0-9a-z]*       # 0 or more alphanum
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position
.*              # 0 or more any character but newline
$               # end of line
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Nice. I always forget about `\K` :-)

Comment: @horcrux: Thanks. `\K` is very usefull when variable-length lookbehind is not supported.

Comment: very nice presentation, clear, clean, precise, and works. thank you for share your expertise

Comment: @JamesBell: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: two more Questions Q1. what exactly ". matches newline" do. Q2. why **Replace all work** for this code but not **replace**

Comment: @JamesBell: 1) `. matches newline` means exactly what it says, it's equivalent to `/s` flag or `(?s)`. 2) I don't know, probably a bug!